# Machine readable pstree output?

Tags: processes

Is there a nice way to get the output of `pstree` in some machine readable machine output without a bunch of code or horrible parsing?

I just really want a list of all descendant processes.

## Edit: specific usecase: get all descendants

```
> useful_pstree $PID

1010
1012
10101
1013
```

a more general usecase might give me beautiful JSON

```
# json_pstree $PID

 { 'pid': 1010,
       children: { ...
```

Although... I don't really know a nice way of easily doing recursion of json structures from the command line (à la `jq`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shell script that prints the output of `ps` starting from the process given as argument and recurses over the child processes. The script is lacking error checking, and you may want to add some options to `ps` depending on the output you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

printps() {
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then
        ps --no-headers $*
        for p in $*; do
            printps $(cat /proc/$p/task/$p/children)
        done
    fi
}

printps $1
```

Comment: Again this is a nice solution... more code than I would want ideally but maybe there is no magic precanned solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a version of `pgrep` that supports filtering by parent PID, then you can use that to get this list. For example:

```
$ pstree -pa 1058
terminator,1058 /usr/bin/terminator
  ├─sudo,1249 -i
  │   └─zsh,1252
  ├─zsh,1250
  │   └─wget,26232 --continue --input-file=-
  ├─zsh,28482
...
```

And with bash arrays and `pgrep`, a breadth-first traversal of this tree:

```
$ pids=( 1058 ); for ((i=0; i < ${#pids[@]}; i++)); do pids+=( $(pgrep -P ${pids[$i]}) ); done; printf "%s\n" "${pids[@]}"
1058
1249
1250
28482
1252
26232
29138
...
```

Depending on what you're using, you could also use `ps` or look in `/proc`.

I have a fairly current version of `pstree` (GNU, 23.1) and it has no option to print machine-readable output.

Comment: So ideally I'd have a utility that requires no code :). I like this way of doing graph traversals... although it depends on being acyclic.